# Create slideshow for images using nstimer?

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

How to create a slide show for the images using NSTimer in iphone

Comment: what have you tried? show us the code you've got so far, no one will just give you a solution, you need to at least show some effort of research :)

Comment: please provide some code or what you have tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

1. Schedule a method to run every second (or as quick as you want the images to switch)
2. Create an array of your images file names
3. In the scheduled method change the UIImageView.image to be one from the images array by index.

There's a post here http://i-tutor.weebly.com/blog.html on how to schedule a method.